# Webpack raw minified css loader

Tags: css, webpack

All I need is to `require` css file to a variable as string, in the same manner as `raw-loader` does, but also minify it.

The original [`css-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) does excess manipulations on css file and produces extra code.

[`css-raw-loader`](https://github.com/catdad/css-raw-loader) is close to what I need but it still got this [extra module](https://github.com/catdad/css-raw-loader/blob/master/css-base.js) which was inherited from `css-loader` and is unnecessary in my situation.

How can it be achieved without creating and maintaining my own loader?

Is there an easy way to incorporate industry-standard `clean-css` into Webpack workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too late, but you can use https://github.com/gajus/to-string-loader
like this `to-string!css?minimize`